# How to assign an external ip to linux server at gcloud?

Tags: linux, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Last several days I'm struggling with a problem.

I have two instances(ubuntu server) on gcloud and I want to assign them their external IP.

And I can ping and ssh to my instances but when I try to do telnet it is not performed.

On gcloud all instances have one internal ip and one external IP.

And they does not know their ip. I get it from gcloud console.

How could I assign it to them?

Also I've tried `sudo ifconfig eth0:0 130.211.95.1 up`

Comment: What do you mean "assign them their external IP"? Why do you need this on the machines?

Comment: @ZacharyNewman a use case I found was trying to run bind on the machine and have it listen on the external IP. It refused to bind to an IP that was not assigned to any local interface.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this to add the external IP to a local interface:

```
ip addr add 130.211.95.1/32 dev eth0 label eth0:shortlabel
```

Replace 'add' with 'del' to remove it once you are done with it.

*shortlabel* can be any string up to a certain (short) length.

Update: also see this [GCE support issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Resource%20Service%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Log&groupby=&sort=&id=172) for related information.

Answer (score 1):

A feature request for this is already filed on [GCE public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=172), however it is not yet implemented. You can star it to get notification if any update posted on the thread.

May you also mention what's your use case? so I can probably provide you with a workaround.

Comment: Ok.
I have two instances and I want to create a cassandra cluster.
Each cassandra instance is needed for two IPs. One for external and one for internal communication.
And when I start cluster and connect to one node from my client, the cassandra node I'm connected to should respond me external IP’s of others nodes. But they don’t know them. And my client has only one node he could be connected to.

Comment: Check out this Python Cassandra Driver. There are examples that show how to connect to multi node cluster with specifying a list of IP addresses for nodes in your client. This IP addresses should be external IP addresses if you're connecting remotely: https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/getting_started.html